# Cannot access Disposed object MVC4 View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I am developing a system in where it will be using a large amounts of drop downs and repeated lists. Therefore to avoid repeated code I have created a `DropDownManagerClass()`, this will allow me to call the Customers drop down from anywhere in the system:

```
public class DropDownManager:BaseManagerClass
{
    public DropDownManager(String connectionString)
        : base(connectionString)
    {
    }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetCustomerDD()
    {

        this.OpenConnection();

        IEnumerable<SelectListItem> dropDown = this._context.Customers.Select(m => new SelectListItem { Text = m.Description, Value = m.CustomerID.ToString() });

        this.CloseConnection();

        return dropDown;


    }

}
```

I then populate my model by calling this **disposable** manager class, you will see I am disposing the object to clean up the connections to the database.

```
  DropDownManager dropdown = new DropDownManager(Global.ConnectionString);

  IEnumerable<SelectListItem> customers = dropdown.GetCustomerDD();
  IEnumerable<SelectListItem> suppliers= dropdown.GetSuppliersDD();

  model.CustomersDD= customers;
  model.SuppliersDD= suppliers;

  dropdown.Dispose();
```

When I debug I notice that customers and suppliers have a SQL statement. So when it comes to my view I think this is where it is trying to execute the SQL to get the data, however being I have disposed `dropdown` it is throwing an error. If I remove `dropdown.Dispose()` then the code works.

My view

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Customer.CustomerID, Model.CustomersDD, new { @class = "large" })
```

Is there anyway I can populate my model with the data and dispose of this manager efficiently?

**Edit** When I call `.ToList()` after the select from customers, I can see the Model now has the result set yet in the view it still gives the error

Comment: I don't quite understand the edit. Did `.ToList()` solve the problem?

Comment: Also, use the `using` statement, so `Dispose` is called, even when there is an exception.

Comment: Sorry edit has been amended. It appears that with an IEnumarable<SelectList> the database query is executed from the view. The exception is being thrown in the view, there are no exceptions before this

Comment: If .Customers.Select(...).ToList() doesn't help, what about Model.Customer object? Is it related to DbContext?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try the code below?  It is a combination of suggestions made here and how I would write my code:

First replace your `GetCustomerDD()`:

```
public List<SelectListItem> GetCustomerDD()
{
    List<SelectListItem> dropDown;
    try
    {
        OpenConnection();

        // .ToList() here makes sure you get the result immidiately
        dropDown = _context.Customers.Select(m => new SelectListItem { Text = m.Description, Value = m.CustomerID.ToString() })
            .ToList();              
    }
    finally
    {   
        // try-finally makes sure you always close your connection
        CloseConnection();
    }
    return dropDown;
}
```

Then call it this way:

```
using (var dropDownManager = new DropDownManager(Global.ConnectionString))
{  
    // using makes sure the DropDownManager is always disposed
    CustomersDD = dropDownManager.GetCustomerDD();
}
```

Does this work?

**By the way**; in your post you state that you dispose `DropDownManager` to close connections, yet in your code you seem to close the connection with `this.CloseConnection()` inside `GetCustomerDD()`.  Are we missing something?  Perhaps you do not need to dispose it to close connections?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is going to work, buuut .... Have you tried using the "using" statement instead of calling .Dispose() manually?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that the query only executes once you start enumerating the results (later), however, as you dispose the dropdown before enumerating the results, then when you try to enumerate them later, the query runs against a context that is already disposed and fails.

You should dispose the context later in the request or enumerate the queries (calling to list) before disposing the request to avoid this problem.

Comment: Calling ToList() does not solve the issue, I can see the results have been enumerated but the issue still remains. Is it because I am using IEnumerable<SelectListItem>?

Comment: Where exactly are you calling ToList(). The moment you call ToList() you should get all the objects in memory so the problem should disappear. Can you show the updated code?

Answer (score 0):

You may have already tried, but did you try changing INumerable to List:

```
List<SelectListItem> customers = dropdown.GetCustomerDD().ToList();
List<SelectListItem> suppliers = dropdown.GetSuppliersDD().ToList();
```

Comment: Yes Tried this and no luck

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about maybe looping through them and adding them to a list, which should hopefully query the database before you pass them to the view?

```
var list = new List<SelectListItem>();

this._context.Customers
    .Select(m => new SelectListItem { Text = m.Description, Value = m.CustomerID.ToString() })
    .ForEach(x => list.Add(x));
```

Just a general thought really. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you use Linq2Entity or Linq2Sql the within a using statement (generally the best way to do it by the way) the query is not executed until you really access the data (binding, using First, Count, ToList or any other method that fetch the data).

You just need to call the ToList() method in the Utils class to "materialize" the results.  It is important to do it INSIDE the DropdownManagerClass and not outside.